# Logical Operation - Addition

Tags: arithmetic

Consider R to hold the value 250 ohms. Now you have been told to calculate "R+150". Will the result be 400 ohms or "250 ohms + 150" as R has a unit whereas 150 does not?

P.S. I know its a stupid question but if someone could clarify, I'd be eternally grateful!

Comment: Until you define a meaning of a sum of a resistance and a number the result is undefined.

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who told you?

Comment: Use Physics SE for such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"250 ohms + 150" is meaningless if we assume that 150 is a pure number.  The addition will only be meaningful if the two quantities have the same units of measurement, in this case, if "150" represents a quantity that is a resistance.  I think you can safely assume that "150 ohms" is what was meant.

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Physical quantities and "common" numbers behave quite differently, because of the way they're defined.

Every physical value is written like $nu$, where $n$ is a real number and $u$ is a unit. The problem arises when you want to manipulate the unit part $u$ with some other (incompatible) unit (including a *dimensionless* unit). You can think that every unit $u$ belongs to some set $S_d$ that possess every other unit with the same physical dimension $d$ (where physical dimensions are values like length, time, energy, ..., and every product of them).

For example

$S_{\text{distance}} = \left\{\text{m},\text{cm},\text{inch},\text{AU},... \right\}$

Of course every non-null set $S_d$ has infinite elements, as every unit $u$ can be multiplied by some real number $a \in \mathbb{R}$, creating a new different unit $au$ that also belongs to $S_d$. More strongly, selecting a fixed $u_0 \in S_d$, every other unit $u \in S_d$ can be written as $a u_0$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ (think of how we convert units of a same dimension, it's just multiplying by a real number, like $\text{m} = 10^3~\text{mm}$).

This way we can define sum of units:

$u_0 + u = u_0 + au_0 = (1+a) \, u_0$

So summing two different units from a same dimension has no problem whatsoever. For example, $1~\text{m} + 1~\text{cm} = 1.01~\text{m}$.

Another thing we can define is the product of units. This is when things get interesting, because if we multiply two not-dimensionless units (that does not have to be the same dimension) we always have a unit from a different dimension. That is, if $u \in S_d$ and $u' \in S_{d'}$, then $uu' \in S_{dd'}$. That is how we define non-base dimensions (like resistance). For example

$\text{resistance} = \text{mass} \cdot \text{length}^2 \cdot \text{time}^{-3} \cdot \text{current}^{-2}$

(is worthy noting that the base dimensions are as arbitrary as any other dimensions, they're just defined like that by convenience, but there is a finite number of base dimensions as we know)

Also, we have an multiplicative identity, that is the dimensionless unit $1$.

In some way, those $S_d$ sets behave very like $R^n$ spaces, as we have an multiplication (in the case of real spaces, it's the Cartesian product) that operates between sets and a sum that operates inside a set, although we didn't defined very well negative or null units. That defines a mathematical ring or even a field if I'm not mistaken.

With all that, we can make a rigorous definition of physical units, but for answering you question, note that we never sum units of different dimensions. That is like summing an vector to a scalar: If it's not defined, *it just not works*. We can think in a lot of ways of making it work, but it will be a brand new definition that does not correspond to the physical reality. So 250 ohm + 150 is as meaningless as $(1,2,3) + 4$.